# The exception of "Expected end of statement or expression"

Tags: jsp

The code is shown below and the error was come with underline code "user.id"/>&&nowPage=".

```
function goPage() {
    var currentPage = parseInt($("#currentPage").val());
    var selectedPage = parseInt($("#selectPage").val());
    if (selectedPage != 0 && selectedPage != currentPage) {
       document.goPageForm.action = "user_ManageUserAllTopics.action?user.id= <s:property value="user.id"/>&&nowPage="+selectedPage;
       goPageForm.submit();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given two `&&` remove one `&` when you pass second parameter in `url`,also change `""` to `''` like below :

```
 document.goPageForm.action = "user_ManageUserAllTopics.action?user.id= <s:property
 value='user.id'/>&nowPage="+selectedPage;
      //^ use single quote and remove  one &
```